# Correlation definition between two set

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

How can I define correlation between two set x and y:

{$(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3),...(x_n,y_n)$}

Is this definition correct:

Correlation=$\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(Covarianc(x_i,y_i))}{\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(Variance(x_i)Variance(y_i))}}$

Answer (score 0):

Are x and y vectors of random variables? If so you can define the  positive-semidefinite symmetric correlation matrix:

$(\textrm{diag}(\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-\frac{1}{2}})) \mathbf{\Sigma} (\textrm{diag}(\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-\frac{1}{2}})) $

where $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is the covariance matrix of the data.

i.e. the $i^{\textrm{th}}$, $j^{\textrm{th}}$ component of the corrlation matrix is the correlation coefficient for the $i^{\textrm{th}}$, $j^{\textrm{th}}$ data in x and y.